# CPT symmetries for a free Klein-Gordon equation and in minimal coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I'm studying for an exam on relativistic quantum mechanics and one of the issues to prepare is about symmetries of Klein-Gordon equation concerning $C$, $P$, $T$ transformations for a free field, and with an electromagnetic interaction.

So could you help me out a bit? As I understand the general free solution can be written as:

$$
\Psi(\mathbf{x},t) = \int\limits_{ \mathbb{R}^3 }\frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi \hbar)^3}
\frac{1}{2 E_p} \left(
A_\mathbf{p}^{(+)}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_p t} e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}
+
A_\mathbf{p}^{(-)}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}E_p t} e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}
\right)
$$

where: $E_p := \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2c^2-m^2c^4}$
For a special solution (in a box):

$$
\psi^{\pm}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{x},t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}} e^{\mp\frac{i}{\hbar}E_p t} e^{\frac{i}{\hbar} \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}
$$

- $P$ transformation gives: $P\psi_{\mathbf{p}}^{\pm}(\mathbf{x},t) = \psi_{-\mathbf{p}}^{\pm}(\mathbf{x},t)$,
- $T$ transformations gives: $T\psi_{\mathbf{p}}^{\pm}(\mathbf{x},t) = \psi_{\mathbf{p}}^{\mp}(\mathbf{x},t)$ and
- $C$ transformations gives:
  $C\psi_{\mathbf{p}}^{\pm}(\mathbf{x},t) = \psi_{-\mathbf{p}}^{\mp}(\mathbf{x},t)$ //Corrected a mistake thanks to a comment by TwoBs

So what conclusion (if any) I can draw from this about the general solution? And do the conclusions stay valid for a KG equation with minimal coupling ($\partial_{\mu} \rightarrow D_{\mu} := \partial_{\mu} + \frac{i e}{\hbar c}A_{\mu}$)?

Comment: $\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)$ is the field, but who's $\psi^{\pm}_\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{x},t)$? Can you please give more details on your notations?

Comment: @TwoBs This is a single particle problem, so there is no field (as I understand) just a solution to the wave-function equation, like in non-relativistic QM. $\Psi(x,t)$ is a general solution (in $\mathbb{R}^3$), while $\psi_p^{\pm}(x,t)$ are special solutions (in a box of volume $V$), with specific momentum $p = (\pm \frac{E_p}{c},\mathbf{p})$.

Comment: Ok, then there is nothing quantum here.  What you actually have is a just a relativistic wave equation, and asking about other solutions that can be obtained by flipping time, or space, the charge. Btw, I think your definition of C is not quite correct (you should probably flip $\pm$ into $\mp$). The general solution is also written in a slightly non standard notation, with $\mathbf{p}\rightarrow\mathbf{p}$ but it is ok anyway. Since the general solution is a linear combination of the special solutions, you should be able to draw by yourself the conclusion on $\Psi$

Comment: I meant, with $\mathbf{p}\rightarrow-\mathbf{p}$ in front of $A^{-}$ that you can get after changing variables... I am not going to give you the full answer, you can get by yourself, but I just give you a hint: T changes t in - t in the general answer. What do C and P do?